# How to get part of the page from other controller

Tags: php, symfony

My site I have some content can be voted (+/-). It is working fine now, when all content has its own voter.
Now I'm looking for a way to create a single voting bundle with a entity(votedModel,votedId, user, vote).
Basically the bundle is ready. My problem is how to use it. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
class ... extends Controller {
    function showAction(Request $request,$id) {
        ...
        $voter=new Voter('myCOntentType',$id,$userid);

        ...
        return $this->render('...', array('voter'=>$voter->getVoter(),...))
    }
}
```

getVoter() would create the voter view.

- but I'm stacked how exactly start. I tried to call for the other controller in this manner, but can't create the voter form.
- It worked with `$voter=$this->forward('VoterbundleNewAction', array('id=>$id,'user'=>$user)->getContent();`
  But this wasn't I had in mind.

I think my approach is all wrong and I may need to do this as service. I cant find my way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use include or render in your twig template to get other templates' output. So you could create a template (say, voter.html.twig) that contains the HTML for your voting system, and in the Twig, in any place where you need a voter, you could use:

```
{% include "AcmeVoterBundle:Voter:voter.html.twig" %}
```

or

```
{% render "AcmeVoterBundle:Voter:voter" with {"item": item} %}
```

In the first example, you simply include another template (see also: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates), in the latter situation you actually execute another action method of a controller and the output of that is put into your current template (see also: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)